# Efficient method to return (n) number of rows before and after a specific index in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to develop a more efficient method to return values before and after certain predetermined index rows. I'm currently performing this manually.

The important indexes are labelled below (`[500, 2000, 2500, 4200, 7567]`). These are just examples. They can be any index number. I am hoping to automate the code so each of these index values returns `250 rows` plus and minus this number. As the first intended index number is 500, I want to return 250 rows either side of 500. So `250:500` and `500:750`. After I do this for each intended index I `concatenate` them together. The example below displays the process for the first two intended indexes.

At the moment, I'm manually returning the appropriate rows via `.iloc`. This is fine if I don't have many intended indexes to return. But if there are 100 indexes that I need to perform this function on, it becomes quite cumbersome.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

important_indexes = [500, 2000, 2500, 4200, 7567]

df1 = df.iloc[250:500]
df2 = df.iloc[500:750]
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df4 = df.iloc[1750:2000]
df5 = df.iloc[2000:2250]
df6 = pd.concat([df4, df5])

df7 = pd.concat([df3,df6])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create indices in list comprehension:

```
idx = [500, 2000, 2500, 4200, 7567]
N = 3
fin = [i for x in idx for i in range(x-N, x + N + 1) if i in range(len(df))]
print (fin)
[497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
 2497, 2498, 2499, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 4197, 4198, 4199, 4200, 4201, 4202, 
 4203, 7564, 7565, 7566, 7567, 7568, 7569, 7570]

df = df.loc[np.unique(fin)]
print (df.head(10))
             A         B         C         D
497  -0.427715 -0.594448 -0.601282  0.470405
498  -1.822557  0.174358  1.278744  0.600856
499   0.288681 -0.843391  1.085665 -0.688055
500   0.105091  1.205726 -1.983058  0.167988
501   0.672003 -1.203700  0.499095  1.158318
502   0.536697 -0.383856  0.873004 -1.290925
503   1.554669 -0.782812  0.900755 -0.328286
1997 -0.187344 -1.100535 -1.791559 -0.588603
1998 -1.525571 -0.316076  1.276415 -0.297315
1999  0.498313 -0.094936 -0.598474  0.045281
```